# Negative Price Series and Mixed Units

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am working on testing multiple time series (monthy data) for statistical significance. The data has mixed units, and some of the time series have negative prices. The data set includes prices, volatility, geo-political indices (indexed from 100 over time), price time spreads...etc. I thought the best approach is to scale the data using logs and run standard statistical tests (regressions, correlations...etc.), but the negative prices are posing a problem. Does the community have any suggestions on the best way to approach an analysis with negative data series and mixed units?

For people unfamiliar with negative prices, they are very common in energy commodities. The costs of shutting down production, or the benefits received through production tax credits means participants will often sell a commodity at a negative price (ie., you pay to sell it). Prices, therefore can fluctuate widely from negative to positive values.  The units are often mixed - bbls, MWh, GJ, indices scaled from 100 or zero...etc.

Comment: What's a negative price? They pay you to get something?

Comment: That is correct.  You pay to sell your commodity.  Negative prices are very common in energy commodities such as electricity. The costs of shut-down/restart/ramp, or production tax credits often results in negative prices.

Comment: You haven't really explained what you hope to achieve by using a log transform ("scaling" usually refers to a linear transformation, not taking logs) or why that would be required.

Comment: Because of the mixed units across the various time series, I understand standard statistical analysis is not robust enough. A common approach I have seen is to scale the time series with negative numbers, log transform all the data series, then perform the statistical analysis. I was seeking feedback to see if this is a good approach, or whether there are other ways to deal with negative numbers and different units across the time series.

Comment: Having negative prices or different units is not inherently a problem so there is no reason, a priori, to do anything at all. Log transforms are used to "stabilize" variance when we want to use a model with a fixed variance but the variance of the data grows with the level (not a valid assumption when you have negative values). Rescaling is typically used either in procedures that aren't equivariant (e.g. regularization) or for numerical stability. Do you have any of these issues? You're going to have to be more precise about your data and your goal if you want better advice.